# Call powershell script with multiple args from command line

Tags: powershell, batch-file

My final goal is to have a .bat file that calls a powershell script.

This works OK in powershell (but can't be used in a batch file):

```
PS build-directory> .\ps1file.ps1 -ScriptArgs '-arg1="val1"', '-arg2="val2"'
```

But this one (batch file friendly) fails:

```
PS build-directory> powershell -File ps1file.ps1 -ScriptArgs '-arg1="val1"', '-arg2="val2"'
```

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'arg2=val2'.

But it works fine if there is only one param `-arg1="val1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having problems because `ScriptArgs` isn't a valid parameter for using with powershell command line ([documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-5.1)).

You just pass the arguments like this:

```
powershell -File ps1file.ps1 -arg1 "val1" -arg2 "val2"
```

Comment: That's it. After your answer, I still had [this problem](https://i.imgur.com/Iu6HtgH.png) with Cake Build. Before you answer I didn't know if this error was related to the `ScriptArgs` or not. After this answer, being sure that this was the right way (regarding powershell), I made [a bit of research](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/1248#issuecomment-249287930) and I found that arguments containing "." did not work with "-paramName" BUT they work with "--paramName" (two "-"). This finally solved my issue. Thanks for the answer, it helped me decouple one issue from the other.